# Counting with generating functions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

We have buckets of paint in three colours: red, blue and yellow. We have an infinite amount of 3-litre buckets and 6 of 1-litre buckets of each colour. In how many ways can we get 120 litres of paint?

The suggested way of solving the exercise is to use a generating function.

So we get
$f(x) = (\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{(3x)^{i}})^{3} \cdot (\sum_{i=0}^{6}{(x)^{i}})^{3} = \frac{1}{1 - 3x } \cdot \frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x}$

We used to find the common denominator by finding the common denominator of each factor in examples with 1, 2 and 4 litres of paint and then expand them with binomial theorem. Yet it is not possible in that case. What should I do instead? Or maybe there is a better method for that?

Comment: What is the connection between your $f$ and the problem?

Comment: I think there must be something wrong. $ (\sum_{i = 0}^{\infty}{(3x)^{i}})^{3} \cdot (\sum_{i=0}^{6}{(3x)^{i}})^{3} = \frac{1}{1 - 3x } \cdot \frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x} = -\frac{\left(3 x (3 x+1) \left(9 x^2+3 x+1\right) \left(9 x^2-3 x+1\right)+1\right)^3}{(3 x-1)^3}$, definitely not $\frac{1}{1 - 3x } \cdot \frac{1 - x^7}{1 - x}$

Comment: Assume we have only the red color. My way of counting using generating functions would be to use $g(x)=(1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\dots)$ for the 3L buckets and $h(x)=(1+x^6+x^{12}+x^{18}+\dots)$ for the 6L buckets. (And i would set $X=x^3$.) Then $gh=1/(1-x^3)/(1-x^6)=(1+x^3)/(1-x^6)^2=(1+x^3)+2(x^6+x^9)+\dots+(20x^{114} + 20x^{117}) + 21x^{120}+\dots$ which matches the simple argument that we only chose 6L buckets, 0 or 1 or ... or 20. (All obtained colors are equal!) Now for all colors i would take $g^3h^3$ which is $1 + 3x^3 + 9x^6 + 19x^9 +\dots+180642x^{120}+\dots$

Comment: @Jfischer f is the function which is generated by power series with coefficients being the number of ways you can get the given amount of paint. Further reading about the method: [link](https://www.mn.uio.no/math/personer/vit/ragnip/mit_h.pdf)

Comment: @FFjet you're right, there was a typo in the second sum, I've edited it to the correct one.

Comment: @dan_fulea Actually the buckets are 3-litre (and we have an infinite amount of them) and 1-litre ( we have 6 of them). Edited the post to make it clearer.

Comment: Which is the meaning of that $(3x)^i$ in the first series? Please spend some more words on how is the passage from the problem to the generating series. And what is a "different way"? The problem wants to find all possibilities to have a *different color*? Or the way of partitioning is also important, so we can simply replace the three colors *a, b, c* with each 3L and 1L buckets with the clear situation of six colors, first three colors being *a, b, c* with 3L buckets, the other three colors being *A, B, C* with 1L buckets each... ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the following is a satisfactory solution, but I think we should at least get the generating function correct, which it is not in the OP.

My interpretation of the problem is that we want to count the number of solutions in integers to
$$3x_1 + 3x_2 + 3x_3 + x_4 +x_5 +x_6 =r$$
where $0 \le x_i$ for $i=1,2,3$, $0 \le x_i \le 6$ for $i=4,5,6$, and $r=120$.  The generating function for the number of solutions is
$$\begin{align}
f(x) &= (1 + x^3 +x^6 + x^9 +\dots)^3 (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5 +x^6)^3 \\
&= \left( \frac{1}{1-x^3} \right)^3 \left( \frac{1-x^7}{1-x} \right)^3 \\
&= \frac{(1-x^7)^3}{(1-x)^6 (1+x+x^2)^3}
\end {align}$$
We would like to know the coefficient of $x^{120}$ when $f(x)$ is expanded as a power series.  According to the Series function in Mathematica, the answer is $85,292$, but I don't know how Mathematica gets its answer.  One possible pencil-and-paper approach is to apply the method of partial fractions to $f(x)$, but that appears to require more computation than I would like to do.  I would be happy to have someone prove me wrong on that by finding a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use partial fraction expansion to rewrite
$$\frac{1}{(1-3x)(1-x)}=\frac{A}{1-3x} + \frac{B}{1-x}$$
for constants $A$ and $B$
and then use
$$f(x) = \left(\frac{A}{1-3x} + \frac{B}{1-x}\right) - x^7\left(\frac{A}{1-3x} + \frac{B}{1-x}\right).$$